# How to convert different date formats to single one in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have test table where column `sys_created_on(datatype is varchar(15))` is a `datetime` field and we receive two different date formats like below.

03-04-2022 12:49
2/28/2022 10:35

Expected Result is:
03-04-2022 12:49
02-28-2022 10:35

Could you please suggest if there is any way to convert all formats to one format instead..
any suggestions can be appreciated. Please suggest if datatype change can help anything here.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here would be to just convert your text timestamp column to a bona fide timestamp column.  You could achieve this using the `TO_TIMESTAMP()` function along with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    ts,
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(ts, '\\d{1,2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}')
         THEN TO_TIMESTAMP(ts, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi')
         ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(ts, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') END AS ts_real
FROM yourTable;
```

Assuming you had a new timestamp column, you could populate it using the `ts` text column as follows:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET ts_real = CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(ts, '\\d{1,2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}')
                   THEN TO_TIMESTAMP(ts, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi')
                   ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(ts, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') END;
```

Comment: Could we use same case statement while creating a table? here in staging table i will be having the above input and while loading to transform phase this column need to update as expected result assuming there is no other column for same column..

Comment: I don't know if Snowflake's loading tool allows for conversion functions to be run (MySQL's does for certain).  You might have to read in your timestamps as text, and then convert inside Snowflake.  Or, you could fix the data at the source so you don't have this problem when importing.

Comment: @user3840800 You can create your table with a [virtual column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71406601/5298879) that depends on this one. Case statement can define the dependency. That way you'll have both the raw data column as well as its version in your desired format, without duplicated space.

Answer (score 0):

[TRY_TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html) return null if it fails so you can just chain different formats together with [COALESCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html) or [NVL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl.html)

```
SELECT column1,
    TRY_TO_DATE(column1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi') as d1,
    TRY_TO_DATE(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi') as d2
    ,nvl(d1,d2) as answer
FROM VALUES ('03-04-2022 12:49'),('2/28/2022 10:35');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | D1 | D2 | ANSWER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03-04-2022 12:49 | 2022-04-03 |  | 2022-04-03 |
| 2/28/2022 10:35 |  | 2022-02-28 | 2022-02-28 |

which can be merged as

```
,nvl(TRY_TO_DATE(column1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi'),TRY_TO_DATE(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi')) as answer
```

ah, didn't read well enough, to make them all the same, UPDATE but use the "local format" thus just a TO_CHAR

thus:

```
UPDATE table
   SET sys_created_on = to_char(nvl(
       TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(sys_created_on , 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi'),
       TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(sys_created_on , 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi')
   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the separator using [`replace()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace.html):

```sql
    update test_table 
    set sys_created_on = replace(sys_created_on,'/','-');
```

If you're also dealing with different day and month field order, look into [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html) to swap their places:

```sql
    update test_table 
    set sys_created_on = regexp_replace(sys_created_on,
                                        '(.*)/(.*)/(.*)',
                                        '\\2-\\1-\\3');
```

That's in case your `03-04-2022` is in format `dd-mm-yyyy` making it April 3rd, not March 4th. [It's good to know what exact format you're dealing with.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) In extreme cases you might even need to make sure whether your hour field is 24-h or 12-h-based but missing an `am`/`pm` meridiem indicator.

As suggested by [Tim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71405528/5298879) and [Simeon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71405647/5298879) answers, a matching data type is always encouraged. It takes less space, queries faster, enables type-specific functions and maintains validity of data (`varchar` doesn't care if you get February 30th or 32nd day of month 13, at 25:60)

If you want to keep the cookie and eat it too, here's how you can add one [virtual column](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008ixGQKSA2/does-snowflake-supports-computed-columns-in-a-table-while-creating-table) where you'll always see a standardised version of your `sys_created_on`, and another one, which will always interpret it as a proper timestamp. This way you don't need to touch anything in how the table is populated, keep the original, unprocessed data, see how it gets standardised, and also benefit from a `timestamp` data type, while not using up any additional space:

```sql
alter table test_table 
    add column standardised_sys_created_on varchar(15)
        as replace(sys_created_on,'/','-'),
    add column timestamp_sys_created_on TIMESTAMP_NTZ
        as coalesce(
            try_to_date(sys_created_on, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'),
            try_to_date(sys_created_on, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'));
```

To make it faster at the expense of materializing them, you can turn those virtual columns into [generated/computed using `default`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#optional-parameters).